# computer turns itself on when charging

Tags: bug-reporting

For months my computer turns itself on while charging and when my Android phone is plugged in the charging USB. 
That seams to be the combination to make it power up.

It powers after i shut down.

Situation only happens when laptop is charging.

The curious thing is that it powers after a specific time +/-1h even with the screen closed.

ITS a 2014 Acer only boot is Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: I tried to add the log but its too long...

Answer (score 0):

Bios was Enabled for network wake up.

So when I plugged my android Phone to the usb made the Computer power up and start Ubuntu.